# Wordpress returns 400 on ajax request with using fetch

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, fetch-api

Already looked through dozens of topics with the same problem, but did not find any really working solution.

JS:

```
/*let data = {
    test_string: 'SENDED DATA',
    action: 'test_ajax_func'
}*/  // already tried

let data = new FormData();
data.append('action', 'test_ajax_func');
data.append('test_string', 'SENDED DATA');
//let data_usp = new URLSearchParams(data);  // already tried too, both with the object and FormData object

fetch(wp_localize_data.ajax_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,  // JSON.stringify(data) already tried, no differecne at all
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    }
}).then(responce => {
    if(responce.ok) {
        console.log('ajax_request: YEP');
        responce.json().then(data => console.log(data.result));
    }
    else {
        console.log('ajax_request: NOPE');
    }
}).catch(error => console.log('ERROR: ' + error));
```

PHP:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_styles_and_scripts');
function theme_styles_and_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('ajax-test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax-test.js', []);
    wp_localize_script('ajax-test', 'wp_localize_data', ['ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')]);
    wp_enqueue_script('ajax-test');
}

add_action('wp_ajax_test_ajax_func', 'test_ajax_func');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_test_ajax_func', 'test_ajax_func');
function test_ajax_func() {
    $test_string = $_POST['test_string'];
    $returned_string = 'RETURNS '. $test_string;
    
    echo json_encode(['result' => $returned_string]);
    die;
}
```

It looks like everything should be fine, but it keeps returning 400 Bad Request.

But if I change

```
fetch(wp_localize_data.ajax_url, {
```

to

```
fetch(wp_localize_data.ajax_url + '?action=test_ajax_func', {
```

request begins to work, but PHP function does not see $_POST['test_string'] and returns just 'RETURNS ' string.

So, some truly working solution to correctly using fetch API with WordPress even exist?
Cause I begin to think it's better to totally forget about it and just keep using jQuery ajax() all the time.

Comment: Stop pretending you were sending `application/json`, when you are not in fact actually doing that.

Comment: So what's the problem when i really sending json with JSON.stringify(data)?

Comment: In that case, the problem is _that_ you are sending JSON. PHP does not populate $_POST, when you send it JSON.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm wondering why some people saying that you should use JSON.stringify() in the request.

Comment: I don't know, you'd have to ask them. If you wanted to send JSON to a custom script of your own, then you would need to read the data differently (https://stackoverflow.com/q/18866571/1427878) - but here within WordPress, you need to keep sending form/urlencoded data, it won't understand if you send JSON.

Answer (score 0):

add **credentials** to your code

```
fetch(wp_localize_data.ajax_url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    .
    .
    .
```